# Changed IDs not being copied to Area 51 discussion

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When I change my user name and / or description, I can **copy to other accounts** to change all my StackExchange sites simultaneously.

But my ID is not changed on [Area 51 Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), nor [Meta SciFi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/).

**Update:** my ID is also not updated on the main [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site (or rather, it is in my name on my ID page, but not in the bar at the top of the screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Area 51 wasn't properly setting a bit to indicate that the profile was changed. I just fixed the bug, and manually set the bit, so your profile changes should be copied to Area 51 Discussion within an hour.

Comment: Indeed they are, thx.

Comment: Same for [Meta SciFi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yup, it turns out this bug wasn't constrained to just Area 51. It's been fixed network-wide, and we just kicked off a profile-sync of all meta profiles (except A51 Discussion profiles, which will be synced later today).

Comment: Hi Emmett - did you notice the change I made to the question? Another issue found, I think.

Comment: No reply, but it appears to have been fixed since my comment.